# Blender Smooth With subdivision surface

Tags: subdivision-surface

I made this axe and now i want to add subdivision surface to smooth the edges but i got some problems.
This is the axe without the modifier.
[image]

I applied the modifier and now i'm trying to add supporting loops to make edges sharper.
[image]
I dont want this effect on those spots. I want it kinda like in the concept photo. Do u have an idea on how to achieve that?

https://we.tl/t-NlBFZ6mraP

tried to edge slide (g + g) some edges the seams are not dissapearing.
[image]
[image]

Comment: could you please share your object (or at least this part)? https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/

Comment: i added a wetransfer link to the axe

Comment: Do you want to remove the seam that is visible in the result?

Comment: yes. and is there any way to make the other seams less obvious?

Answer (score 1):

It happens because when you want to sharp the angle on the top you create a new edge loop that also sharps the bottom one:

[image]

You can keep the topology as it is and simply slide the edge loop along the bottom (<kbd>G</kbd><kbd>G</kbd> and you'll be good:

[image]

Comment: i will try. thank you

Comment: it kinda work but the seams are not fully erased in some cases when i need to do the same things on both sides

Comment: maybe show a screenshot of the problem on the other side